# How can I have function that returns an array as the Data for a ForEach View in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've had functions that return something update views to some success, with something like

```swift
func nextRequest() -> Date {
    notificationRequests().sorted().first?.toDate() ?? Date()
}

...

Text("Next: \(nextRequest().hourMinute())")
 .font(.caption)
```

But somehow, when I try to achieve the same automatic view updating by using `ForEach` and an array like this

```swift
func notificationRequests() -> [UNNotificationRequest] {

    let currentUNuserNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    var arrayOfRequests: [UNNotificationRequest] = []
    let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    currentUNuserNotificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
        arrayOfRequests = requests
        sema.signal()
    }
    sema.wait()

    return arrayOfRequests
}

...

Section(header: Text("Upcoming notifications")) {
    ForEach(notificationRequests().sorted(), id: \.self) { request in
        
        NavigationLink(destination: EditNotificationView(request: request)){
            Text("\(request.toDate().convertDateFormatter())")
        }
        
    }
}
```

it only updates on the app's startup.

My solution has been to make an `@State` local variable and whenever the array changes, to also have an action that updates the `@State` variable, like this

```swift
    @State var upcomingNotificationRequests: [UNNotificationRequest] = []
...

Section(header: Text("Upcoming notifications")) {
    ForEach(upcomingNotificationRequests.sorted(), id: \.self) { request in
        
        NavigationLink(destination: EditNotificationView(request: request)){
            Text("\(request.toDate().convertDateFormatter())")
        }
        
    }
}
...

Button("Set Random Notifications") {
    setRandomNotifications(numberOfNotifications: 5)
    self.upcomingNotificationRequests = notificationRequests()
}
```

which is kind of annoying and doesn't work well when coming back from a `NavigationLink` to another `View`.

Is there something I can do to make just the function that returns the array update the `View`?

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/yangnom/notifications-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write your function the way you are trying to.

If you read the docs on `getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler:)` they say:

> This method executes asynchronously, returning immediately and executing the provided block on a secondary thread when the results are available.

That means that the function returns immediately, before the results are available. arrayOfRequests will still be empty at the time you are trying to return it. You need to refactor your function to take a completion handler.

Comment: Does my use of semas in `notificationRequests()` not resolve this?

Comment: What I would expect is for your use of `DispatchSemaphore` to block the main thread until the call returns (Which is bad. Don't do that.) I'm not sure why it isn't blocking. Don't use semaphores. Learn to use completion handlers.